# Scatter plot with Jzy3d

Tags: java, scatter-plot, scatter, scatter3d, jzy3d

I am using Jsy3d to draw a 3d scatter plot in Java. However, I noticed that the drawing order of the points seems to be based on the order of the given List of Points, not on the distance to the camera. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You are right, rendering is based on point declaration. Why would you change this?

To change the scatter rendering, simply override `Scatter.draw(...)`

You may use `Camera.getDistance(coord)` to get the distance to Camera. This method is already used by `BarycenterOrderingStrategy` in `Graph` to order the drawables (but this won't work for your scatter as it is a primitive Drawable).